# ReactNative : NavigatorExperimental : NavigationCardStack seems to have default grey background. How to to remove it?

Tags: react-native

My app as a fullscreen background image that wraps NavigationCardStack.

```
<Image source={bkg} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
        <NavigationCardStack
          navigationState={this.state.navState}
          onNavigate={this._handleAction.bind(this)}
          renderScene={this._renderScene.bind(this)}
          style={styles.navigator}
        />
      </Image>
```

I tried to add style background: 'transparent' to NavigationCardStack but it's not working.

Any idea?